# Reverted a database and the Unicode chars got converted to garbage

Tags: database, unicode, import, backup

I have been making regulate backups of my forums database each and every day. Today I had to revert the forums to an earlier backup.

Command I use to backup my databases:

```
mysqldump --opt -hMY_HOST -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME 2> error.txt | gzip > DATABASE_NAME_2010_11_06_14_38.gz 2> error.txt
```

I used phpMyAdmin to import the database.

After I reverted the forums all the Unicode chars where converted to Garbage. 
Example: http://www.everydayfiction.com/forums/index.php/topic,2376.msg11198.html#msg11198

How do I convert these garbage chars back in to there Unicode version or an equivalent ASCII version?

What did I do wrong when exporting or importing the Backup file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly did nothing wrong at all; [mysqldump has a bug where it can doubly-encode utf8 data](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28969). Check the dump file byte-by-byte - does it look like this is what's happened?